# Unable to create Azure VM from uploaded VHD

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm attempting to make a custom image from a local VHD that contains a basic CentOS 8 install.

I've followed the guidance on preparing the install to be hosted on Azure here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-centos

however when I create the VM from the image it fails to boot with the below error messages indicating the boot paths can't be found...

[image]

If I check my local VM which (which is using the original copy of the VHD) then it clearly shows that one of the paths (/dev/mapper/cl-root) does exist...

[image]

Needless to say it does boot and work absolutely fine locally so I can only imagine it has something to do with the upload of the VHD or some configuration of the Azure Disk or VM.

If I mount the the drive (as a second drive) on another working VM I see:

[image]

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling myself to get a working vm uploaded onto azure, but I do recall reading that LVM was not recommended. My guess is that the initrd image on azure is not the same and doesn't have the kernel modules or the config necessary to map the LVM device.  If you can, try cloning them onto non-LVM partitions.

You might want to take a look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-generic).